# How properly create entity in @PostConstruct?

Tags: java, spring-boot, entitymanager, postconstruct

I try to create some entity in @PostConstruct in my SpringBoot app

```
    @PostConstruct
    void load() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setRating(Math.random());
            imageList.add(new Image());
            item.setImages(imageList);
            itemRepository.save(item);
}
```

I have error **detached entity passed to persist: com.amr.project.model.entity.Image;**

I tried adding @Transactional but i find that @Transactional dont work with @PostConstrcut and it`s dont work.

How i can create entity properly?

Comment: See the answer here : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194647/postconstruct-on-jpa-entity-not-called-in-spring-boot

Comment: Share your Image Entity code, problem might be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I_AM_PAUL commented, JPA Entities are not Spring beans, so @PostConstruct won't ever be called.
Try using @PreLoad JPA annotation

```
    @PreLoad
    void load() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Item item = new Item();
            // And so on...
    }
```